# Lodash find by regExp match

Tags: arrays, regex, object, find, lodash

Is it possible to find in array of objects, using lodash, a regexp?
ex:

```
a=val+"@"
b="@"+val
_.find(obj.dbColumns,{attr:{data-db-name: ***CONTAINS a || CONTAINS b*** }})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function that tests each element.  The [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) gives this example:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];

_.find(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
```

so something like this may be what you are looking for:

```
_.find(obj.dbColumns, function(o) {
    return (new RegExp ([a,b].join('|'))).test( o.yourAttribute );
});
```

or if you just want a substring search, not a regular expression:

```
_.find(obj.dbColumns, function(o) {
    return
        o.yourAttribute.indexOf(a) >= 0 ||
        o.yourAttribute.indexOf(b) >= 0;
});
```